# Can this matrix be negative definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

Let $d = 12$ and $m = 6$, and denote by $0_n$ and $I_n$ the zero matrix and the identity matrix of size $n \times n$.

Let $D_+ \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ be a **diagonal** matrix with **positive** diagonal entries and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be defined by
\begin{align*}
D = \begin{bmatrix}
-D_+ & 0_m\\
0_m & D_+
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Let $B = B(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ have the form
\begin{align*}
B = \frac{1}{2} (D \bar{P}+ \bar{J}^{-1}\bar{P}^\intercal\bar{J}D), \qquad \text{with }\bar{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
P & P \\ P & P
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \bar{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{J} & 0_m \\ 0_m & \hat{J}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $P,J \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ are defined by
\begin{align*}
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\Upsilon & \Gamma \\
0_3 & \Upsilon
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \hat{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
I_3 & 0_3 \\
0_3 & J
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
for $\Upsilon, \Gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ **skew-symmetric** matrices, $J \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ a **diagonal** matrix with **positive** diagonal entries.

My question is:

> Is it possible to find a **diagonal** matrix $Q = Q(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ (for $x \in [0,L]$), such that the matrix $M = M(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$
>   \begin{align*}
> M(x) = Q'(x)D + Q(x)B + B^\intercal Q(x)
> \end{align*}
>   is **negative definite** for any $x \in [0,L]$ ?

(Here $B^\intercal$ denotes the transpose of $B$.)

*Remark:* the diagonal of $B$ contains only zeros (since $\Upsilon$ is skew-symmetric), hence the diagonal of $QB+B^\intercal Q$ contains only zeros.

Any suggestion or reference is welcome. Thank you.